# Fantasy book where some youth escape the conquest of their kingdom and come back with Sten guns to free it

Tags: story-identification, books

OK many years ago ( I am 57 now and this was when I was about 12) I read a fantasy book that has never left my memory but can't be recalled properly. In it a kingdom (?) was ringed with mountains. When it was attacked the people were easily defeated. A few youths escaped over or under the mountains and found a more modern world outside(?) armed with Sten guns they found/got there these youth defeat the invaders. Help! I dearly liked this book but have never found it again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You don't happen to recall the cover art, do you?  How many youth were there?  Were they all boys?

Comment: Presumably this is a British novel if it mentions _Sten guns_. And I'd guess it was a children's book. Is there anything else you can remember about it?

Comment: A youth liberating a medieval-level kingdom with a force armed with Sten guns matches "The Sword of the Spirits" by John Christopher, but the other details don't really match (without a lot of contortion)